# Backbone: How to validate if a Model already exist in a Collection?

Tags: backbone.js

Given this Backbone Collection

```
define  [
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'cs!models/floor'
], ( _, Backbone, Floor ) ->
return Backbone.Collection.extend
  model: Floor
  url: ->
    return '/api/hotels/' + @hotelId + '/floors'
  initialize: (models, options) ->
    if ( options.hotelId )
      @hotelId = options.hotelId
      @.fetch()

  parse: (response) ->
    response.floors

  alreadyExist: ->
    @.filter( (floor) ->
      return floor.get('number') == @.attrs.get('number')
    )
```

and adding a new Model from a view the way below, how can I validate if the model already exist within the collection ?

```
add_floor: (e) ->
  console.log ' Saving Floor '
  e.preventDefault()
  floorNumber =  $('input[name=floorNumber]').val()
  floorDescription = $('input[name=floorDescription]').val()
  return new NoticeView({ message: "Please enter a Floor Number.", displayLength: 10000 }) unless floorNumber
  if ! @collection.add({ number: floorNumber}).alreadyExist()
    @collection.create({ number: floorNumber, description: floorDescription }, {
      error: (model, response) ->
        # $(e.target).removeClass('waiting');
        new ErrorView({ message: "Problem saving Floor " + response.responseText, displayLength: 10000 })
      success : (model, response) ->
        console.log model
        console.log response
        new NoticeView({ message: "Floor successfully saved.", displayLength: 10000 })
    })
  else 
    new ErrorView({ message: "Floor already exist." + response.responseText,        displayLength: 10000 })
```

Comment: Collection does not allow you to do that :) it throws a error (In any case there is just a minor variation in your models and you want to validate it, bind to `add` event and validate back there)

Comment: I cannot realize how to validate it the way you say. I will do it server side. Thanks Deeptechtons.

Comment: i will come back with an example :) so that it would solve the problem

Answer (score 20):

Backbone collections proxy the Underscore.js iteration functions which are useful in these cases.

If you have an existing model instance, to check whether it exists in the collection you can just do something like:

```
var myModel = new Floor();

// the following line logs true if model is in collection, false if not.
console.log(myCollection.contains(myModel));
```

If you do not have an existing instance of the model, which from your example suggests may be the case, you can use the `find` or `findWhere` underscore functions, for example:

```
var floorNumber =  $('input[name=floorNumber]').val()
var myModel = myCollection.findWhere({ floorNumber: floorNumber });
```

If  `find` or `findWhere` return a model, which you could easily check using a `typeof` comparison then you will know whether the model exists in the collection or not.

Comment: Hi can we use findwhere if we are check for cid

Comment: @Pascal: You can't use the `findWhere` function proxied by Backbone to search for a model's `cid` as the `cid` property is not a model attribute. To do this you would need to use the native Underscore `find` function like this `var myModel = _.find(myCollection.models, function(model){return model.cid == "c15";});`

Answer (score 0):

findWhere on a collection will not result in JavaScript error but will not not find a model neither. A proper way of checking if a collection contains a model is to use underscore's find like this:

```
var model = _.find(collection.models, function (model) { return model.id == 

id_to_be_searched; });
var found = collection.contains(model);

if (found) {
    // do stuff
}
else {
   // do stuff   
}
```